# How to inject Context instance into the type converter?

Tags: android, android-room

I have a type converter like:

```
class DateConverter {
    Context mContext;

    public DateConverter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public Foobar toFoobar(String str) {
        return App.get(mContext).getComponent()
                .getFoobarManager().convert(str);
    }
}
```

The problem for me is that I have no idea to inject context into the DateConverter instance.

PS:
the project is using dagger2, so I prefer inject instead of reference to a static Context instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: replace context with mContext inside toFoobar method.

Comment: you can use TypeConverter with constructor params from Room  2.3.0-alpha03.
check this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/64973320/3901000

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor to  `public DateConverter()` as context we will add through dagger2.

If you have used dagger2 in your project there must be any component class. Component is basically an interface in application which lets views inject through dagger. There must be some methods which having name `inject()` with different parameters for example

```
    public abstract void inject(MainActivity activity);
    public abstract void inject(DaggerApplication daggerApplication);
```

create your own method there for your `DateConverter`

```
public abstract void inject(DateConverter dateconverter);
```

Now add use this inject method in your `DateConverter` , the way you have used it in other classes. Also define  below code in your `DateConverter`

```
    @Inject
    Context context;
```

Comment: ok, we have a inject method for context now, but where is the point to call?

Comment: dagger basically follow abstraction so you can simply use this context if you injected your view. make sure your context is providable in AppModule class .

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work because the DateConverter instance is a private member of Dao and which code is generated by Room, *not writing by hand*.