# Room TypeConverter with constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have Room `TypeConverter` and I need to inject parameter to it's constructor

```
class RoomConverters(moshi Moshi) {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromUserActionLog(data: UserActionLogModel): String {
        return moshi.adapter(UserActionLogModel::class.java).toJson(data)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toUserActionLog(json: String): UserActionLogModel {
        return moshi.adapter(UserActionLogModel::class.java).fromJson(json)}
    }
}
```

But when I can not annotate `TypeConverter` to database object with contructor;

```
@Database(entities = [SsidModel::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(RoomConverters::class)   
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun ssidDao(): SsidDao
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 19):

You can create Room TypeConverter with constructor parameters from version **2.3.0-alpha03**

Release notes:

> Room now has APIs for providing instances of type converters such that
> the app can control their initialization. To mark a type converter
> that will be provided to Room use the new annotation
> @ProvidedTypeConverter

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.3.0-alpha03

In your case you should add @ProvidedTypeConverter to RoomConverter

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter    
class RoomConverters(moshi: Moshi)
```

Create converter at db creation time and pass it to database builder:

```
val roomConverter = RoomConverters(Moshi())
val db = Room.databaseBuilder()
         .addTypeConverter(roomConverter)
         .build()
```

Also you can use DI framework e.g. Dagger2

Comment: Thanks - now is there any way to do this with per-field converters like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61776742/851699

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3901000/m-myalkin can you give example of hilt with ProvidedTypeConverter, not able to do it

Answer (score 10):

Now that 2.3.0 of Room library is released. It is possible to instantiate Room type converters and provide them to database builder.

Add `@ProvidedTypeConverter` annotation to the `TypeConverter` class.

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class RoomConverter(moshi Moshi) {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromUserActionLog(data: UserActionLogModel): String {
        return moshi.adapter(UserActionLogModel::class.java).toJson(data)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toUserActionLog(json: String): UserActionLogModel {
        return moshi.adapter(UserActionLogModel::class.java).fromJson(json)}
    }
}
```

Mention the TypeConverter in the `@TypeConverter` annotation of the database abstract class.

```
@Database(entities = [/* entities here */], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(RoomConverters::class)   
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ......
    // your code here
    ......
}
```

Now build the database using the static method `databaseBuilder` of `Room` class and provide TypeConverter using the method `addTypeConverter()`

```
val roomConverter = RoomConverter(moshi)
val appDb = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            applicationContext,
                            AppDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME
                        )
                            .addTypeConverter(roomConverter)
                            .build()
```

Comment: If anyone is unable to get this to work in the converter class and getting the error
unresolved reference moshi in the converter class then do this 



@ProvidedTypeConverter
class RoomConverter(private val moshi Moshi) {

Answer (score 2):

I use dagger-android, and faced same problem. 
Solution is when creating AppDatabase

```
@Provides @Reusable
fun provideDatabase(context: Context, moshi: Moshi): AppDatabase = 
    Room.databaseBuilder(...).build().apply { AppDatabase.moshi = moshi }
```

AppDatabase is simple RoomDatabase:

```
@Database(
    entities = [OrderEntity::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
@TypeConverters(DbConverters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var moshi: Moshi
    }

    abstract fun orderDao(): OrderDao
}
```

Then use this companion object in converter:

```
class DbConverters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun orderInfoToString(orderInfo: OrderInfo?): String? = 
           AppDatabase.moshi.adapter(OrderInfo::class.java).toJson(orderInfo)

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToOrderInfo(value: String): OrderInfo? = 
          AppDatabase.moshi.adapter(OrderInfo::class.java).fromJson(value)
}
```

This is looking ugly, I guess, but works. Maybe using static/companion object with `@Reuseable` scope is a bad idea.
Moshi, though, is provided using `@Singleton` scope in AppModule, so basically live through entire application life

Answer (score 2):

I checked documentation even for the newest rc version (`2.2.0-rc01`) and there is no way to do that. I think it's a joke that we can't register custom TypeConverters in DatabaseBuilder, so I created bug for that on [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142086380).

Answer (score 0):

As of August 11th 2020 there's still no fix for this from Google. Check either of these workarounds in the meantime.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142086380
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121067210

Comment: Version 2.3.0 of Room released on April 21, 2021 now supports this capability, thankfully.