# A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution with ROOM and @Database annotation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room for offline storage. My model contain List which Room does not support and i write typeconverters but now i am getting this error. when i remove @Database annotation then error goes but with @Database annotation it is displaying the error. here is my all relevant classes.

here is my Dao

```
package com.example.mvvm.room

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import com.example.mvvm.models.Result

@Dao
interface MovieDao {
    @Query("Select * from Result")
    fun readMovieList():MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Result>>

    @Insert
    fun insertData(result: Result)

    @Delete
    fun deleteAll()
}
```

here is my Database class

```
package com.example.mvvm.room
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.*
import com.example.mvvm.MyTypeConverter
import com.example.mvvm.models.Result

@Database(entities = arrayOf(Result::class),version = 1)
@TypeConverters(MyTypeConverter::class)
abstract class MovieDatabase:RoomDatabase(){
   companion object{

      private var INSTANCE:MovieDatabase?=null
      fun getInstance(context: Context):MovieDatabase? {
         if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized(MovieDatabase::class) {
               INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MovieDatabase::class.java, "movie.db").
               fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                  .allowMainThreadQueries()
                  .build()
            }
         }
         return INSTANCE
      }
   }
   abstract fun movieDao():MovieDao
}
```

here is my model

```
package com.example.mvvm.models

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.TypeConverters
import com.example.mvvm.MyTypeConverter

@Entity(tableName = "result")
data class Result(
    @ColumnInfo val adult: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo val backdrop_path: String,
    @TypeConverters(MyTypeConverter::class)
    @ColumnInfo val genre_ids: List<Int>,
    @ColumnInfo val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo val original_language: String,
    @ColumnInfo val original_title: String,
    @ColumnInfo val overview: String,
    @ColumnInfo val popularity: Double,
    @ColumnInfo val poster_path: String,
    @ColumnInfo val release_date: String,
    @ColumnInfo val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo val video: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo val vote_average: Double,
    @ColumnInfo val vote_count: Int
)
```

type converter class

```
package com.example.mvvm

import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

class MyTypeConverter {

    companion object{
        private val gson = Gson()
        @JvmStatic
        @TypeConverter
        fun toJson(mInt : List<Int>):String{
            return gson.toJson(mInt)
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @TypeConverter
        fun fromJson(string : String):String{
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<Int>>(){}.type
            return gson.fromJson(string, type)
        }
    }
}
```

here is the error

```
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
```

Comment: `@field:TypeConverters(MyTypeConverter::class)`, [How to apply Room TypeConverter to a single field of an entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61776375/how-to-apply-room-typeconverter-to-a-single-field-of-an-entity/61776742#61776742)

Comment: stilling getting the same error

Comment: also, try to use `List` instead of `ArrayList` in Dao

Comment: how does this effect?

Comment: instead storing the list in database , convert the list in json and store the json as string in database , when you retrieve the record, convert the json into list

Comment: I do not made this model. data is coming from moviedb api. how can i change the model

Comment: I had similar error and found the issue and fixed it. You might have done a similar error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133657/after-adding-kapt-plugin-a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotl/63139756#63139756

Answer (score 7):

You can compile in debug mode to get more detail about your error and find where is the problem.

Go to **Gradle menu / Other / compileDebugKotlin** (right sidebar on android studio)  you should have more detail about the error and then you can post it here to have more help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in your `MovieDao` at `@Query("Select * from Result")`

It should be `@Query("Select * from result")`

Comment: i changed but no effect

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by changing MutableLiveData to LiveData in MovieDao readMovieList and changing delete annotaion to Query(Delete from result)

Answer (score 0):

> For queries that return multiple values, you can use List or Array. [Query](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query)

```
@Query("select * from result")
fun readMovieList(): MutableLiveData<List<Result>>
```

also, add `field` target to `TypeConverters` annonation in entity

```
@field:TypeConverters(MyTypeConverter::class)
```

[How to apply Room TypeConverter to a single field of an entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61776375/how-to-apply-room-typeconverter-to-a-single-field-of-an-entity/61776742#61776742)

Answer (score 0):

For me, downgrade the plugins version to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"
```

works, but didn't figure out the cause.