# Android Room: manually provided TypeConverter with @ProvidedTypeConverter throws runtime error

Tags: android, android-room

I have this type converter:

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class BackgroundTasksMemoryConverter(
    private val gson: Gson,
) {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(serialized: String): BackgroundTasksMemoryDb {
        return gson.fromJson(serialized, BackgroundTasksMemoryDb::class.java)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(dataStructure: BackgroundTasksMemoryDb): String {
        return gson.toJson(dataStructure)
    }
}
```

which I use like this:

```
myRoomDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            MyRoomDatabase::class.java,
            DatabaseConstants.DATABASE_NAME
        ).apply {
            addTypeConverter(BackgroundTasksMemoryConverter(gson))
        }.build()
```

With MyRoomDatabase being:

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        BackgroundTasksMemoryDb::class
    ],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(
    value = [
        BackgroundTasksMemoryConverter::class,
    ]
)
internal abstract class MyRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val backgroundTasksMemoryDao: BackgroundTasksMemoryDao
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is the correct approach for manually instantiated converters. However, I get this error at runtime:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.techyourchance.android.debug, PID: 30902
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type converter com.techyourchance.android.database.converters.BackgroundTasksMemoryConverter@29dc933. Annotate TypeConverter class with @ProvidedTypeConverter annotation or remove this converter from the builder.
```

Am I doing something incorrectly, or this is a bug?

Comment: Are you declaring the converter in the `MyRoomDatabase` class? (e.g. `@TypeConverters(BackgroundTasksMemoryConverter::class`) (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67367971/3773452)

Comment: @RicardoMarkiewicz, yes. Added MyRoomDatabase's code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to had been related to the fact that `BackgroundTasksMemoryDb` was both an entity that had a corresponding table, and a serializable data structure that had a converter. I just couldn't get rid of this error.
If I use exactly the same approach for serialization/deserialization and `@ProvidedTypeConverter` with another data structure, which doesn't have a table on its own, it works.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are actually two approaches to creating converters in Room.

1. Use `@ProvidedTypeConverter` and `addTypeConverter`

If you choose this approach, you need to manually add the converters using `addTypeConverter` during the instantiation of the RoomDatabase, as you have done above. With this approach, you don't have to declare the converter class with TypeConverters since Room may not properly reflect your converters.

2. Using `@TypeConverters` annotation

In this second approach, you don't need to add your converter class during Room Database instantiation (`addTypeConverter`). Instead, you only have to put the converter class within the `@TypeConverters` annotation.

The runtime issue in your code above is due to redundancy. You need to choose which approach you want to use.

**To address your runtime issue, simply you only need to remove the @TypeConverters annotation in the RoomDatabase's class.**